# Texworks pdf viewer has taken over all my pdf files

Tags: pdftex, pdf

All my pdf files have suddenly become Texworks PDF files regardless of whether they were generated from Texworks or not. As i work as a copy-editor for non-LaTeX as well as LaTeX files I can't do my work when they don't have the red adobe icon. I must have changed something from default but don't know what. Help

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you use the [tag:texworks] tag.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: if you are on windows right click on any pdf file then `open with` and select `choose another app`, then you can re-choose acrobat and check the box `always use this app to open pdf files`

Comment: Thank you David Carlisle. You have saved my day.